# outputLabel does not render after fadein jquery

Tags: jquery

the p:outputLabel does not render after the fadein jquery had ran. Only the PainelLogin.png does render.
The p:outputLabel does render but fadeout immediatly without any action,etc...

HTML FORM :

```
  <div id="login-form">
    <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="#{bundle.login_lblEMail}" />
    <p:inputText id="j_username" name="j_username"
    value="#{loginMB.usuario.nome}" />
    </div>
```

SCRIPT :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("div#login-form").fadeIn("slow");
        document.getElementById('login-form').style.display = 'block';
});
```

CSS :

```
#login-form {
    background-image: url("../resources/imagens/PainelLogin.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -moz-opacity: 0.70;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.70;
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    display:none;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Would you please help me with this issue ? thanks in advance..  Alex.

Comment: `z-index: -1;` could be thats it?

Comment: sorry. It does does not work on IE. thats my issue.

Comment: Ive removed z-index but did not fix that. thx

Comment: IE special thing is often `position:...` needed in css.

Comment: no deal with position. had tried also visibility in css and jquery but no success

Comment: I noticed that backing the outer div to position:relative the fields are render, but the layout messed up. How can I proceed with it ?

Comment: Fields might be having `position:absolute` and hence messed up. Can you paste the CSS for fields ?

Comment: .j_login {
 font-size: 13px;
 font-family: Verdana, "Verdana CE", Arial, "Arial CE",
  "Lucida Grande CE", lucida, "Helvetica CE", sans-serif;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: I debugged the css by IE developer tools and figured out some issues like display: inline-block; (I was trying to let two divs aligned in the same row.

Comment: But the weird thing to me is when I set height div to 200px the panel goes forward the fields and when I disabled height, the content is showed up.

Comment: last comment sounds like a typical `block` space problem. if you can try to give your animated `div` an `position:absolute` like @anpsmn mentioned, and on top erase all opacity rules, fadeIn does know how to handle it in different browsers, you dont need `-moz-` etc.

Comment: and what kind of html type did you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
#login-form {
    background-image: url("../resources/imagens/PainelLogin.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    /*-moz-opacity: 0.70;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.70;*/
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    display:none;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>
```

to show you how jQuery syntax is written, here your example translated.
you dont need the full long syntax of javascript if you allready use jQ a specially on the same element..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#login-form")
    .css({
        display:'bock', /*haha should be 'block' but is not needed in your code */
        border: '1px solid #000000'
    })
    .fadeIn(1000);
});
```

`$().fadeIn()` needs a value in ms,

your `document.getElementById` is not necessary if you use `<p>` elements, they are blocks by there nature, but if you style them, use the much quicker native CSS or try to learn a bit about jQuery syntax.
Maybe you also get errors by your choosen HTML-type, which is IE sometime pissed of, but this [thinker.io](http://tinker.io/826f8/1) works so far. I can't test it on IE now, i'm jumpig around on a 11 year old MAC. As i have seen the problem was also reproduce-able here, so i assume the change above will work. let me know..

**Edit:** in this thinker.io i changed also your html markup to show that they become visible

**Edit:** display:'bock', i like that- i let it so now! :)

Comment: It did not work. The weird thing is I removed the height:200px and painelLogin begins to be rendered. It got messed up but it renders

Comment: so it is clear, there is a bug somewhere else in your code. depends on what is the container of your `div#login-form`